# Issue with multiple logs files forwarding with rsyslog?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rsyslog

I have a use case, where I need to forward multiple log files to remote server.

```
    //Log Files

 1. /var/log/boot.log
 2. /path/to/tomcat/tomcat.log
 3. /path/to/app/app.log
```

I have added 3 conf files in `/etc/rsyslog.d/`

```
 #/etc/rsyslog.d/boot.conf

    $ModLoad imfile
    $InputFilePollInterval 10
    $InputFileName /var/log/boot.log
    $InputFileTag boot-log
    $InputRunFileMonitor
    $InputFilePersistStateInterval 100

    #/etc/rsyslog.d/tomcat.conf

    $ModLoad imfile
    $InputFilePollInterval 10
    $InputFileName /path/to/tomcat.log
    $InputFileTag tomcat-log
    $InputRunFileMonitor
    $InputFilePersistStateInterval 100

    #/etc/rsyslog.d/app.conf

    $ModLoad imfile
    $InputFilePollInterval 10
    $InputFileName /path/to/app.log
    $InputFileTag app-log
    $InputRunFileMonitor
    $InputFilePersistStateInterval 100
```

To include these file I've added this line `$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf`. 
but in `/var/log/syslog` just boot logs are adding up rest of the configs are getting ignored.

RsysLog Version: **8.1907.0 (aka 2019.07)**

Comment: If you are matching on the tag (eg `tomcat-log`) you might want to add a colon to the setting, eg `$InputFileTag tomcat-log:`.  Also, ensure rsyslogd hasa permission to read the path to the files. Try `rsyslogd -dn` to get lots of debug output, which may provide some error messages on why lines are ignored, and which config files are read.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the answer should be in the rsyslog's documentation:

```
$ModLoad imfile # needs to be done just once
# File 1
$InputFileName /path/to/file1
$InputFileTag tag1:
$InputFileStateFile stat-file1

$InputFileSeverity error
$InputFileFacility local7
$InputRunFileMonitor

# File 2
$InputFileName /path/to/file2
$InputFileTag tag2:

$InputFileStateFile stat-file2
$InputRunFileMonitor
# ... and so on ...
# check for new lines every 10 seconds $InputFilePollingInterval 10
```

In that way, you have re-defined the module load itself, that should be defined before the file includes.