# I wonder how to add recursively logfiles to syslog?

Tags: linux, syslog

My need is to send all `/var/log/[dir]/*.log` files to the `rsylog.conf` file while i cannot guess what [dir] is or [dir]s are.

I followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/67127263/1469161

I can send `/var/log/*/*.log` into a list and configure `rsylog.conf` via a script and then restart the rsyslogd service.

Is it possible to do it dynamically, or recursively into `rsylog.conf` ?

I can resume : How to add files to the *imfile* module recursively ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry :( But it [cannot be done yet](https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/issues/2588) :

> *Any plans on adding support for recursive wildcards in path?*
>
> actually not - it will further complicate already complex code AND drags quite some performance. Note that we need to keep watches on all and every directories in between. I admit I also do not fully understand why such a feature may really be needed. If there is a hard need, it can of course be done. Maybe even as a sponsored project.

Once it's said :

- In order to catch the legacy log stack, I listed all files (from a python script), and for each I use the **logger** command with decent options to send them directly to the network based syslog aggregator and I verify each line exists in the target database and then delete the .log(.gz) file.
- In order to let the live log stack, I listed all files with an anacron line and I add all files to the syslog appender.

Done this way. I'll see if journald can handle such a situation.

Comment: Why the hell this reply has been voted down ?